# Why the where clause doesn't work with count on xQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I'm currently working at a project that requires me some xQueries with a certain dataset. This is a fraction of the said dataset:

```
<root>
 <Transaction>
  <Person>
   <Full_Name>  Katherine  Eaton</Full_Name>
   <Age>87</Age>
   <Ssn>314-44-0462</Ssn>
   <Credit_Card>
    <Cc_Provider>JCB  15  digit</Cc_Provider>
    <Cc_Number>5547858204343354 </Cc_Number>
   </Credit_Card>
   <Bought_From>
    <Date>2021-02-13</Date>
    <Price>$34478.90</Price>
    <Status>Undisputed </Status>
    <Merchant>
     <Shop> McDonalds</Shop>
     <Phone>+1-371-602-9171x83395</Phone>
     <Resides_In>
      <Province>Colorado</Province>
      <City>West  Morgantown</City>
      <Address>834  Walker  Canyon</Address>
      <Lat>80.2658445</Lat>
      <Lon>156.324095 </Lon>
     </Resides_In>
    </Merchant>
   </Bought_From>
  </Person>
 </Transaction>
 <Transaction>
  <Person>
   <Full_Name>  Charles  Wright</Full_Name>
   <Age>55</Age>
   <Ssn>420-62-7501</Ssn>
   <Credit_Card>
    <Cc_Provider>Diners  Club  /  Carte  Blanche</Cc_Provider>
    <Cc_Number>4743336688954504 </Cc_Number>
   </Credit_Card>
   <Bought_From>
    <Date>2020-09-24</Date>
    <Price>$477.99</Price>
    <Status>Undisputed </Status>
    <Merchant>
     <Shop> Subway</Shop>
     <Phone>6922856236</Phone>
     <Resides_In>
      <Province>Wisconsin</Province>
      <City>West  Sherri</City>
      <Address>807  Cordova  Ferry</Address>
      <Lat>-6.079631</Lat>
      <Lon>-150.485761 </Lon>
     </Resides_In>
    </Merchant>
   </Bought_From>
  </Person>
 </Transaction>
 <Transaction>
  <Person>
   <Full_Name>  Scott  Gibbs</Full_Name>
    <Age>52</Age>
    <Ssn>717-01-2401</Ssn>
    <Credit_Card>
     <Cc_Provider>VISA  19  digit</Cc_Provider>
     <Cc_Number>371936215412640 </Cc_Number>
    </Credit_Card>
    <Bought_From>
     <Date>2021-01-06</Date>
     <Price>$2.52</Price>
     <Status>Disputed </Status>
    <Merchant>
     <Shop> American  Apparel</Shop>
     <Phone>(453)737-9365</Phone>
     <Resides_In>
      <Province>Nebraska</Province>
      <City>Sheilamouth</City>
      <Address>70734  Frye  Ridge</Address>
      <Lat>51.8881985</Lat>
      <Lon>-147.147829 </Lon>
     </Resides_In>
    </Merchant>
   </Bought_From>
  </Person>
 </Transaction>
 <Transaction>
  <Person>
   <Full_Name>  Wesley  Underwood</Full_Name>
   <Age>82</Age>
   <Ssn>265-39-3658</Ssn>
   <Credit_Card>
    <Cc_Provider>Discover</Cc_Provider>
    <Cc_Number>30354748203291 </Cc_Number>
   </Credit_Card>
   <Bought_From>
    <Date>2021-07-20</Date>
    <Price>$691.93</Price>
    <Status>Disputed </Status>
    <Merchant>
     <Shop> Amazon</Shop>
     <Phone>(274)381-6022</Phone>
     <Resides_In>
      <Province>Minnesota</Province>
      <City>Jorgeview</City>
      <Address>877  Debra  Way  Apt.  305</Address>
      <Lat>-59.405851</Lat>
      <Lon>3.413555 </Lon>
     </Resides_In>
    </Merchant>
   </Bought_From>
  </Person>
 </Transaction>
 <Transaction>
  <Person>
   <Full_Name>  Scott  Gibbs</Full_Name>
   <Age>52</Age>
   <Ssn>717-01-2401</Ssn>
   <Credit_Card>
    <Cc_Provider>VISA  19  digit</Cc_Provider>
    <Cc_Number>371936215412640 </Cc_Number>
   </Credit_Card>
   <Bought_From>
    <Date>2020-12-03</Date>
    <Price>$1.21</Price>
    <Status>Disputed </Status>
   <Merchant>
    <Shop> Amazon</Shop>
    <Phone>(274)381-6022</Phone>
    <Resides_In>
     <Province>Minnesota</Province>
     <City>Jorgeview</City>
     <Address>877  Debra  Way  Apt.  305</Address>
     <Lat>-59.405851</Lat>
     <Lon>3.413555 </Lon>
    </Resides_In>
   </Merchant>
  </Bought_From>
 </Person>
</Transaction>
```

I would like to obtain the person who got the most disputed transactions of all with this query:

```
for $xml in 
doc("dataset_100.xml")/root/Transaction
 where $xml//Status = "Disputed"
 for $x in
 (
  for $name in distinct-values(//Full_Name)
  order by count(//Full_Name[. = $name]) descending
  return <x>{$name}</x>
 )
 return fn:concat(
           $x, 
           ' - Contexted Transactions - ', 
           xs:string(count(//Full_Name[. = $x])))
```

but the result is everytime the list from the first element to the last with all the transactions made, either disputed or undisputed:

```
`Katherine  Eaton - Contexted Transactions - 3
 Charles  Wright - Contexted Transactions - 6
 Scott  Gibbs - Contexted Transactions - 3
 Wesley  Underwood - Contexted Transactions - 3
 Andres  Hanna - Contexted Transactions - 2`
```

That i know is incorrect since i've tested it in neo4j, but i don't really now where to put hands here now.

Edit: I actually found out how to write the missing part of code that before didn't let me post. So, i'm really sorry and i want to thank you for the answer, Martin Honnen, but this is the actual xml.

Comment: I sure hope these are completely fictitious names, SSNs, and credit card numbers.

Comment: Your query expects there to be a `<root>` and a `<Transaction>`, but your sample data doesn't include those things. Please make it representative.

Comment: BTW, in XQuery 3.0, you can use `declare context item` to embed your document and query together into a single thing that can be directly run together. That makes building (and testing) fully standalone [mre]s much easier.

Comment: ("Please make it representative" -- meaning, "please test that your query can actually be run against the data you provide, and that it returns the specific output you state that it does when run against that data")

Comment: ...btw, towards better meeting the "minimal" part of the MRE definition, feel free to take out parts of the data that the query doesn't care about. The fewer irrelevancies present, the better.

Comment: Yes the data is completely random generated with the faker class in python

Comment: Yeah in the full data there are <root>,<Transaction> and a <Person> tag that encloses data, but for some reason it didn't show when i wrote the question lol (sorry it's my first interaction, so i'm a total noob even on question)

Comment: I have edited my answer to work the the new structured input you have added.

Comment: Thank you so much, you don't even know how much you've helped me!! Again i wanna thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For the seemingless unstructured data you have shown you could first restructure it using `tumbling window`, the rest then is grouping by `Full_Name` and counting and ordering and selecting the first

```
(for $person in
for tumbling window $transaction in root/*
start  $s when $s instance of element(Full_Name)
where $transaction[self::Bought_From]/Status/normalize-space() = 'Disputed'
return <transaction>{$transaction}</transaction>
group by $name := $person/Full_Name/normalize-space()
order by count($person) descending
return $name || ':' || count($person)) => head()
```

For the edited, strucured sample this reduces to

```
(for $transaction in root/Transaction[normalize-space(Person/Bought_From/Status) = 'Disputed']
group by $name := normalize-space($transaction/Person/Full_Name)
let $count := count($transaction)
order by $count descending
return $name || ': ' || $count) => head()
```

which then yields `Scott Gibbs: 2`.